# Grouping items based on last added item in set

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have an app where I store debug information from several sources. The data is stored in a class like the following:

```
public class DebugMessage
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OccurredOn { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public string TextMessage { get; set; }
    public MessageTypes Type { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }

    public int Count {get;set;}

    public bool Same(DebugMessage other){...}
}
```

Now, I already have setup indexes and maps/reduce for each item I need. What I would like to do now is the following:

When ADDING a new item to the collection, If this items "looks the same" (by calling the Same method on the item and passing in the last added item in the collection), I would like to just update the last added item and do not add a new item. If the items are not the same, I would like to add it to the collection.

I guess I can do this with some kind of Map/Reduce, but I can't wrap my head around this. I'm new to Raven and don't know how to do the above (or even if that's possible).

Any directions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your in the Same method to the map/reduce index, and group based on the values that make you consider the two things to be the same.
Alternatively, query for similar debug message, and update the result.

Comment: Thanks Ayende. I just want to group items similar to the last inserted item. I do not want to group all similar items (I understand how to do so, and I'm actually doing that with the Tags). Already though on the query thing, now... Can I query the last inserted document, without having to resort to the indexes? Because for this to work, I must be sure that I always get the last inserted item, no matter if it was indexed or not, and I don't want to have to run the WaitForNonStaleResults...

Comment: You want the absolute last inserted document? You can keep a document "config/last-entries" and check those.